# Найти с помощью Регулярного выражения

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Дана последовательность строк.
Вывести строки, содержащие "cat" в качестве подстроки хотя бы два раза.
Вход:

```
catcat
cat and cat
catac
cat
ccaatt
```

Необходимо использовать

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.rstrip()
```

Comment: Регулярка r"(?<=cat)cat"

Comment: А если на вход подаются строки, тогда надо использовать``` import sys
                                                                                            for line in sys.stdin:
                                                                                            line = line.rstrip()``` КАК тогда реализовать регулярное выражение. Как считать строки?

Comment: from sys import stdin

for line in stdin:
  print(line, end='')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно такого решения:

```
from sys import stdin
import re

for line in stdin:
    if re.search(r"(?<=cat)cat", line, flags=0):
        print(line, end='')
```

Comment: ещё такой вариант тоже работает if re.search(r"cat.*cat", line, flags=0):